# Trouble passing a string from an array to a variable within a for loop

Tags: twig

Im setting a "category" and passing it to a template that I'm including:

```
    {% set categoryA = {
      category: "categoryA",
    }
    %}

    {% include "something.twig" with categoryA %}


    {% set categoryB = {
      category: "categoryB",
    }
    %}

    {% include "something.twig" with categoryB %}
```

This is working fine but I'm repeating a lot of code which I want to avoid (in my actual code there are more than 2 categories).

Im trying to put the categories in an array and include something.twig for each one, passing a different category for each instance:

```
    {% set categories = ['categoryA', 'categoryB', 'categoryC', 'categoryD', 'categoryE'] %} 


    {% for i in categories %}

      <h3>{{ i }}</h3>

      {% set categoryOption = {
        category: {{ i }},
      }
      %}

      {% include "something.twig" with categoryOption %}

    {% endfor %}
```

The title in the h3 is printed OK however the categoryOption category is passed as [object Object] rather than the string name as I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you use category in the "something.twig":

```
...
{{ category|default }}
...
```

So you can use "include" like:

```
{% include "something.twig" with { category: 'Name of Category' } %}
```

Full code:

```
{% set categories = ['categoryA', 'categoryB', 'categoryC', 'categoryD', 'categoryE'] %} 


    {% for i in categories %}

      <h3>{{ i }}</h3>

      {% include "something.twig" with { category: i } %}

    {% endfor %}
```